# How can i inject this piece of code in to a object value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, material-ui, key-value

Is there anyway i can add the headstyles object in to the headText object? i alreasy injected the headStyles object in to headConfig

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

```
const headStyles = {
    backgroundColor:'green',
    borderRadius:10,
    padding:7
}

// CSS Styles
const useStyles = makeStyles( theme => ({ 

box: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width:'100vw',
    display:'grid',
    textAlign:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginTop:'10vh',
    color:'white'
},

avatar: {
    justifySelf:'center',
    width: theme.spacing(19),
    height: theme.spacing(19),
    margin: theme.spacing(6),
},
headText: {
    position: 'relative',
    color: '#aaa',
    zIndex:1,
    top:'10vh',
    // TRYING TO ADD (headStyles) IN HERE SOMEHOW  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------
},
headConfig: headStyles
}))
```

Comment: if yoy need it as `headText.headStyle` then just write `headStyle,` inside of the object, otherwise if you need to assign it together, use `...headStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure i understand your question. I assume you want to merge the two objects. If this is the case, you can use the (`...`) spread operator.

```js
const a = {a: 2}
const b = {b: 3, ...a} // here we add all the elements of a
console.log(b) // {b: 3, a: 2}
```

So in your example you should be able to do:

```
headText: {
    position: 'relative',
    color: '#aaa',
    zIndex:1,
    top:'10vh',
    ...headStyles
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object spread operator(`...`). For example

```js
const headStyles = {
    backgroundColor:'green',
    borderRadius:10,
    padding:7
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ 
    box: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width:'100vw',
        display:'grid',
        textAlign:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginTop:'10vh',
        color:'white'
    },
    avatar: {
        justifySelf:'center',
        width: theme.spacing(19),
        height: theme.spacing(19),
        margin: theme.spacing(6),
    },
    headText: {
        position: 'relative',
        color: '#aaa',
        zIndex:1,
        top:'10vh',
        ...headStyles // using object spread operator to merge headStyles
    },
    headConfig: headStyles
}))
```